# Python os.listdir cannot find folder on hosting

Tags: python, django

So i am using Django and this code

```
faces = {}
for f in os.listdir('faces'):
    if 'png' in f:
        faces[f.split('.')[0]] = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(str('faces/' + f), 0), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

doesn't work. Django says it can't find this folder. Why? How can i scan folder on my hosting?

Comment: Depends of where the current working directory of the python application is. If the relative path of the faces directory is next to the current module, you can do: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "faces")`

Comment: where is your folder? can you provide the directory tree... Also make sure directory will be with respect to `BASE_DIR`...